# Giving a Client in a TCP Socket a unique ID in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcpclient, tcp

I have made a server in C that accepts any amount of clients to connect to it and stream a message.

I have a separate file called client.c that connects to this server using a socket. I want to give each client that is connected to the server a unique ID specified by the user.

The clients can be on a separate system or the same system.

Would I have to create a client server that keeps track of all the clients currently active?

Thank you!

Comment: Have the server hand out a unique ID like a GUID or similar to use internally along with the user's entered ID.

Comment: Someone needs to keep track of the active clients. Makes logical sense that it's the server itself that does that (not a seperate server).

Comment: Why? The accepted socket's remote IP address:port pair is already unique. 'Unique ID specified by the user' is already a contradiction in terms.

Comment: A 'unique ID specified by the user' can be done (and indeed is done by just about every web site that allows people to register a username to log in with).

Comment: @JeremyFriesner If that is what the OP is actually talking about, there is no question here to answer. SO itself is a prominent exception. Usernames are not unique here.

Comment: Using the "ID", you want to identify the client(-machine), the client-program's instance, the user, the connection, ...?